# Pycharm: MultipleInstanceError: Multiple incompatible subclass instances of PyDevTerminalInteractiveShell are being created

Tags: debugging, console, ipython, pycharm

In PyCharm, if I run a script in debug mode (with debug console on), then stop at a breakpoint, and try to type something into the console, I get:

```
MultipleInstanceError: Multiple incompatible subclass instances of PyDevTerminalInteractiveShell are being created.
```

Does anybody know what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: This seems to be a conflict with Jupyter notebook and Pycharm.  I had some code that was using `IPython.display`.  Once I commented out those lines the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had this issue when using ipdb in another terminal from the same code. I had ipdb present in file A, and a terminal with an ipython shell open running this code. I commented out the ipdb bits from file A and ran the debugger in pycharm and this error started up. When I closed the shell I had open in my terminal the error went away.